# Building a hash tree using XML::DOM in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, xml-parsing, xmldom

I want to parse a simple XML document to hash using the [`XML::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aDOM) module.

```xml
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<Select>
  <book>
    <prop Name = "prop1" Title = "title1" />
    <prop Name = "prop2" Title = "title2" />
  </book>
  <fruit>
    <prop Name = "prop3" Title = "title3" />
    <prop Name = "prop4" Title = "title4" />
  </fruit>
</Select>
```

and the expected output is-

```perl
$VAR1 = {
  Select => {
    book  => {
               prop => [
                 { Name => "prop1", Title => "title1" },
                 { Name => "prop2", Title => "title2" },
               ],
             },
    fruit => {
               prop => [
                 { Name => "prop3", Title => "title3" },
                 { Name => "prop4", Title => "title4" },
               ],
             },
  },
}
```

I have written the code which is:

```perl
use strict;
use XML::DOM;
use Data::Dumper;

my @stack;
my %hash;
push @stack,\%hash;

my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;
my $doc = $parser -> parsefile('demo.xml');
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();
my $rootnode = $root->getTagName;

################################################################

foreach my $node ($doc->getElementsByTagName($rootnode)){
    push @stack,$stack[$#stack]->{$rootnode};
    my @childnode = $node->getChildNodes();

    foreach my $child(@childnode){
        if($child->isElementNode){
            my $childname = $child->getNodeName();
            pop(@stack);
            push @stack,$stack[$#stack]->{$rootnode} = {$childname,{}};
            my @childnodes2 = $child->getChildNodes();

            foreach my $subchild(@childnodes2){
                if($subchild->isElementNode){
                    my $subchildname = $subchild->getNodeName();

                    my $name = $subchild->getAttributes->getNamedItem('Name')->getNodeValue;
                    my $title = $subchild->getAttributes->getNamedItem('Title')->getNodeValue;
                    pop(@stack);
                    push @stack,$stack[$#stack]->{$rootnode}->{$child->getNodeName()} = {$subchildname,{}};    #{} contains $name or $title
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

print Dumper(\%hash);
```

I think, I am not able to correctly push and pop in array. Also, I don't want to use `XML::Simple` and recursion.

How can I do this in Perl?

Comment: Could you perhaps define (in prose or in pseudocode), what rules produce the desired output? It seems that you want to treat attributes as child tags (`<foo bar="baz" />` like `<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>`), and that you want to group multiple tags into an array, if they are siblings and of the same name. Or is the purpose of this parsing just to fill in the `prop` fields, while the rest of the structure is constant?

Comment: Also please expand on what you mean by "XML::Simple and recursion" and why you want to avoid it.

Comment: @amon yes you are right.The desired output is produced with the help of XML::Simple library. I am just trying to find a way to do this with the help of XML::Dom without the use of any recursive function because of memory constrains when the xml become large

Comment: @user2001559 A *well-written* recursive solution is not likely to consume *that much* more memory than an iterative one. It is often useful to write the code in a recursive fashion, where it can be easily understood, and then transform the code to an iteration (see [Chapter 5 of Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/05FromRecursionToIterators.pdf) for inspiration, and extensive discussion).

Comment: @user2001559: I assume you are having memory problems using `XML::Simple`? It most likely that the issue is due to holding the *entire* XML tree in memory, as any additional memory used by recursive parsing will be relatively insignificant. Of course, any solution that creates the same hash structure will use the same amount of memory, so you will have to consider a streaming XML parser like `XML::Twig`. Unfortunately any other software that relies on the `XML::Simple` data format will have to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, assuming that the whole document follows a strict schema with one `Select` as root, any child nodes of different names (collisions won't be handled), and any numbers of `prop`s for these child nodes, of which the `Name` and `Title` field are interesting alone.

This is the preamble, I also used `Carp` for better error handling.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.012;
use XML::DOM;
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp;
```

Here is the main code. It launches a parser (assuming the documenent is in the special `DATA` filehandle), and passes the resulting document off the `make_data_structure` subroutine. I frequently consider to let the script `die`, to catch errors as early as possible.

```
{
    my $xml_parser = XML::DOM::Parser->new;
    my $document_string = do{ local $/=undef; <DATA> };
    my $document = $xml_parser->parse($document_string) or die;

    my $data_structure = make_data_structure($document) or die;
    print Dumper $data_structure;
}
```

This is the subroutine that does all the work. It takes a document and returns a hashref adhering to your format.

```
sub make_data_structure {
    my ($document) = @_;
    my $root = $document->getDocumentElement;
    my $rootname = $root->getTagName // "undef";

    didnt_expect_anything(but=> "Select", as=> "the root tag", got=> $rootname)
        unless $rootname eq "Select";

    my $dsc = +{ $rootname => +{} };
    CHILD:
    for my $child ($root->getChildNodes) {
        next CHILD unless $child->isElementNode;

        my $childname = $child->getTagName
            // couldnt_get("the tag name", of=> "a $rootname child");

        $dsc->{$rootname}{$childname} = undef; # unneccessary iff we have props
        PROP:
        for my $prop ($child->getChildNodes) {
            next PROP unless $prop->isElementNode;

            my $propname = $prop->getTagName // "undef";

            die didnt_expect_anything(but=> "prop", got=> $propname)
                unless $propname eq "prop";

            my $attributes = $prop->getAttributes
                // couldnt_get("the attributes", of=> "a prop node");

            # for minimum code duplication, and maximum error handling,
            # use dataflow programming, and `map`. 
            my ($Name, $Title) =
                map { $_->getNodeValue // couldnt_get("the node value", of=>"the attribute") }
                map { $attributes->getNamedItem($_) // couldnt_get("the named item $_", of=> "the prop attributes") }
                    qw/Name Title/;
            my $propvalue = +{
                Name    => $Name,
                Title   => $Title,
            };

            push @{ $dsc->{$rootname}{$childname}{$propname} }, $propvalue;
        }
    }
    return $dsc;
}
```

The following are custom error handling subroutines to make the above code more expressive.

```
sub didnt_expect_anything {
    my %args = @_;
    my $expected = $args{but} // croak qq(required named argument "but" missing);
    my $role     = $args{as}  // "a tag name";
    my $instead  = $args{got} // croak qq(required named argument "got" missing);
    croak qq(Didn't expect anything but "$expected" as $role here, got "$instead");
}
sub couldnt_get {
    my ($what, %args) = @_;
    my $of_what = $args{of} // croak qq(required named argument "of" missing);
    croak qq(Couldn't get $what of $of_what);
}
```

Of course, the correct output is produced, but this is *not* the correct way of getting there — CPAN was made to be used.

A part of the problem with your implementatin is (aside from the missing error handling), that you do some convoluted gymnastics with your "stack".

Before the first iteration of your outer loop, the `@stack` is `+{}` (a reference to an empty hash).

The line `$stack[$#stack]->{$rootnode}` accesses the last element of the stack (better written as `$stack[-1]`), treats the value as a hash ref, and looks up the entry named `$rootnode`. This evaluates to `undef`. You then push this *value* onto the stack. Chaos ensues.

Comment: yeah as i am new to perl these array of hashes are freaking me out.As you said the code is somewhat hardcoded. By the way thanks...i will try some improvements